# How to Kentico membership provider used in two web applications

Tags: kentico

I have a CMS web site and a separate Web application that both need to query the same CMS membership provider. I purchased separate license for both sites but when I invoke the web application I get the error

The requested domain name is not configured for any website: //siteBdoman-name/application

If you're an administrator of this site, you need to go to Site Manager -> Sites and use the following domain name either in the Site properties or add a new domain alias: siteBdoman-name

I do not want to create new web site as this has to point to membership of the first site. I checked that the Site name, guid etc. are both exactly the same on both sites.

Answer (score 1):

> If you're an administrator of this site, you need to go to Site
>   Manager -> Sites and use the following domain name either in the Site
>   properties or add a new domain alias: siteBdoman-name

You don't have to create new web site. [Here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Setting+domain+names+for+sites) is how you set domain aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be a load balancer issue. I have the load balancer forwarding the request to the first kentico site by default which does not find correct license for given domain name.
I fixed this issue by removing default binding on the first site and routing the traffic correctly.